# How do i display images from MySQL database in a JavaScript image slider?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have following code which gets me all the images from the database. All these images are displayed 3 in a row and then next row starts. i want an image slider that takes all the images from the database and displays them. Any help including a JavaScript code would be very helpful as i'm not really good at it. thanks!

```
$sql = "SELECT FILE_NAME FROM images LIMIT 0,6";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("bad request: $sql");
        $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($i%3 == 0) 
        {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        echo"<td><img src='user_data/{$row['FILE_NAME']}' width=200 height=200></td>";
        if($i%3 == 2) {
            echo"</tr>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting a question. f you still have specific issues, you can post a specific question including details of what you have tried so far. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic Slideshow-from-PHP application. It can easily be modified or built upon. Image names (`file_name`) are pulled from the database, then pushed into a JavaScript array of image src values. Make sure you also specify the images directory (where the images are actually stored) to match your own. A simple image preloader is included, as the slideshow autoplays.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'images')
  or trigger_error('Connection failed.', E_USER_NOTICE);
}
$conn->set_charset('utf8');
$paths = [];
$dir = "./pics"; // images directory (change to suit)

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `file_name` FROM `images`");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($file);
while ($stmt->fetch()){
  $paths[] = $dir . "/" . $file;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Slideshow from PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <!-- may set first image src in markup so initially visible -->
  <img id="slide" src="./pics/image1.jpg" alt="slideshow">
</div>
<script>
var time = 5000,    // time between images
    i = 0,              // index for changing images
    images = [],    // array of img src from PHP
    preloads = [],      // array of preloaded images
    slide = document.getElementById("slide");

images = <?php echo json_encode($paths); ?>; // from PHP to Js array
var len = images.length;

function changeImg(){
  slide.src = preloads[i].src;
  if (++i > len-1){
    i = 0;
  }
  setTimeout(changeImg, time);
}
function preload(){
  for (var c=0; c<len; c++){
    preloads[c] = new Image;
    preloads[c].src = images[c];
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  preload();
  setTimeout(changeImg, time);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just clarifying a request by PM: The first database image is shown first up by the JavaScript - check this by removing the src attribute from the image tag. If per chance there are large slow-loading images (possibly reducing the first image showtime), try increasing the time variable in the load setTimeout call. If only the first image from the database is needed, just add LIMIT 1 to the end of the query string. Both the PHP and Js scripts will get the first image only, without problems.

Comment: Removing the src attribute just shows 'slideshow' written and then i have to wait five seconds before an image appears. i want the slideshow to start from the first image which i can't figure out, please help, thanks!

Comment: That initial delay is modified by just changing the time arguement in the second setTimeout call near the end of the code. The value of time is 5000 (millisec), so changing that call to something like   setTimeout(changeImg, 50);   will show the first image straight away on your local server. Note that for a real server, running the slideshow instantly on page load may not be the best for users with slower connections, especially if there are many images. The 5 sec delay was intended to allow some preloading to occur.

Comment: Great, Thanks for your help!